# Connection string for connecting to Azure SQL Database via Azure AD

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

How can I build connection string for connecting to Azure SQL Database using Azure AD account?
Currently, I am using the following but it does not seem to be correct. It does not use Authentication Type: Active Directory Password.

Part of PowerShell script I am using:

```
server=$Server.database.windows.net;initial catalog=$Databasename;Authentication=Active Directory Password;Integrated Security=False;uid=$Username;password=$Password
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I followed the sample provided by Microsoft in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure

However, this does not work; I am using powershell to create registered servers and the sample connection string does not work there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue; It was actually the order of properties.

The following connection string worked

```
Data Source=$Server.database.windows.net;initial catalog=Master;User ID=$Username;password=$Password;authentication=Active Directory Password
```

However, this does not work

```
Data Source=$Server.database.windows.net;initial catalog=Master;authentication=Active Directory Password;User ID=$Username;password=$Password
```

The only difference is the order of "Authentication" tag. 
I never thought order of properties matter in `ConnectionString`.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, they use this format:

```
Data Source=n9lxnyuzhv.database.windows.net; 
Authentication=Active Directory Password; 
Initial Catalog=testdb;  
UID=bob@contoso.onmicrosoft.com; 
PWD=MyPassWord!";
```

So try to use `PWD` instead of `Password`.

Comment: Brandi Thanks for your comment.
I actually tried that format:


“Data Source=$Server.database.windows.net;Authentication=Active Directory Password;initial catalog=Master;UID=$Username;PWD=$Password”


However, it did not even populate password in "Registered Servers" in SQL Server.