# Is it possible to connect using Azure AD with MFA for Entity Framework calls via Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Azure database from the VS package manager console - e.g.

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString "Some connection string that let's me connect with AzureAD MFA" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

The closest I got was using this [connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959962/connection-string-for-connecting-to-azure-sql-database-via-azure-ad), but I got an error saying that MFA was required, which makes sense! Is there another way to specify the connection to authenticate via AAD and prompt me for MFA, similar to the way SSMS can do it?

Answer (score -2):

As far as I known, you can use C# to connect Azure SQL database with the use who enables Azure AD MFA.The C# program uses the interactive mode of authentication, which supports Azure AD multi-factor authentication (MFA). For instance, a connection attempt can include a verification code being sent to your mobile phone. For more details, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db).